# Inheritance with base class constructor with parameters

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

Simple code:

```
class foo
{
    private int a;
    private int b;

    public foo(int x, int y)
    {
        a = x;
        b = y;
    }
}

class bar : foo
{
    private int c;
    public bar(int a, int b) => c = a * b;
}
```

Visual Studio complains about the `bar` constructor:

> Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter `x` of `foo.foo(int, int)`.

What?

Answer (score 202, accepted):

The problem is that the base class `foo` has no parameterless constructor. So you must call constructor of the base class with parameters from constructor of the derived class:

```
public bar(int a, int b) : base(a, b)
{
    c = a * b;
}
```

Comment: Why does not *C#* let me inherit the two-parameter constructor without having to redeclare it with a reference to the base constructor?

Comment: @Ant_222 You cannot inherit a constructor. You can inherit a class, which should be properly constructed, and therefore you need to call its constructor.

Comment: I understand it is impossible in *C#*, and am asking why. Since the inherited class receives the methods from the base class, why cannot it recieve the constructor, too? Writing `public bar(int a, int b) : base(a, b) {}` makes no sense when all I need is the constructor of the base class.

Answer (score 30):

I could be wrong, but I believe since you are inheriting from foo, you have to call a base constructor. Since you explicitly defined the foo constructor to require (int, int) now you need to pass that up the chain.

```
public bar(int a, int b) : base(a, b)
{
     c = a * b;
}
```

This will initialize foo's variables first and then you can use them in bar. Also, to avoid confusion I would recommend not naming parameters the exact same as the instance variables. Try p_a or something instead, so you won't accidentally be handling the wrong variable.