# Overload error when adding objects to list

Tags: c#, .net, list, web-services, wcf

I have written a web service and constructor that adds objects to my list. I am getting an error that makes no sense to me because I am passing in the 3 parameters I should be passing in.

The error is:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'myArticleID' of
>   'MainPage.GetTileDetails.GetTileDetails(string, string, int)'

Here is my code:

**Web Service:**

```
[OperationContract]
List<ViewDetails> ViewDetails();

[DataContract]
public class ViewDetails
{
    [DataMember]
    public string TitleView { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string BodyView { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int ArticleID { get; set; }

    public ViewDetails() { }
    public ViewDetails(string myTitleView, string myBodyView, int myArticleID)
    {
        this.TitleView = myTitleView;
        this.BodyView = myBodyView;
        this.ArticleID = myArticleID;
    }
}
```

**Project where i am using web service**

```
 public async void ViewData()
    {
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        List<GetTileDetails> tileList = new List<GetTileDetails>();

        var res = await client.ViewDetailsAsync();
        for (int i = 0; i < res.Count; i++)
        {
            tileList.Add(new GetTileDetails(res[i].TitleView, res[i].BodyView.Substring(0, 170) + " ..."), res[i].ArticleID);
        }
        tileGridView.ItemsSource = tileList;
    }

public class GetTileDetails
    {
        public string TitleView { get; set; }
        public string BodyView { get; set; }
        public int ArticleID { get; set; }

        public GetTileDetails() { }
        public GetTileDetails(string myTitleView, string myBodyView, int myArticleID)
        {
            this.TitleView = myTitleView;
            this.BodyView = myBodyView;
            this.ArticleID = myArticleID;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting that error? I am passing in (string, string, int)....

Comment: you seem to have an extra comma in `GetTileArticleDetails`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inheritance with base class constructor with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696006/inheritance-with-base-class-constructor-with-parameters)

Comment: @jstreet where is the extra comma?

Comment: `string ,myTitleView` has an extra comma.

Comment: I see, that was a copy/paste error on my end. Did not fix the issue

Comment: I believe you have a misplaced `)` in this line: `tileList.Add(new GetTileDetails(res[i].TitleView, res[i].BodyView.Substring(0, 170) + " ..."), res[i].ArticleID);`, right after `" ...")`

Comment: If you would like to post that as solution I will mark it as answered @jstreet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
tileList.Add(new GetTileDetails(res[i].TitleView, res[i].BodyView.Substring(0, 170) + " ..."), res[i].ArticleID);
```

with this one:

```
tileList.Add(new GetTileDetails(res[i].TitleView, res[i].BodyView.Substring(0, 170) + " ...", res[i].ArticleID));
```

Note you have a misplaced `)` right after `" ...")`.