# Why do we have to pass values from derived class constructor to base class constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

```
namespace Sample
{
    public class Program
    {
        static int x;

       public Program(int Y) {  
            x = Y;
           Console.WriteLine("one value base class constructor called");
        }  

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {         
            Program prog = new s(10);           
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class s: Program {

        public s(int k):base(10)
        { 
           Console.WriteLine("derived class constructor called");

        }       
    }
}
```

Why is the base class constructor called first? If I have a parameterized constructor defined in the base class, then it is mandatory for the derived class constructor to pass the values to base class constructor from derived class.

I wanted to know the reason why it is mandatory? If no values are passed to the base class constructor then compiler gives the error message saying '**there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter**'.

I am not asking whether or not I have to pass the values to base class but my question is why do I have to do that? Why is the that the base class constructor is to be called first?

Comment: Is this not a side-effect of inheritance?

Comment: It's the way inheritance works, you derive from the base.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inheritance with base class constructor with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696006/inheritance-with-base-class-constructor-with-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

You've answered your own question:

> As we all know that the base class constructor is called before the derived class constructor.

Since your base class only have a constructor that must accept a parameter, you must supply this parameter when calling it.

If your base class would have a parameter-less constructor, then the compiler would be happy with `public s(int k):base()`, or even just `public s(int k)` (since `base()` will be added implicitly at compile time).

However, since you explicitly wrote a constructor to class `Program`, the compiler does not provide the default, parameter-less constructor, and therefor **the only way to instantiate the `Program` class is by calling it's only constructor and passing the relevant parameter.**

Comment: Excellent answer. Beautifully written. Superbly clear.

Comment: No worries. I don't know how on earth you got a down-vote!