# How to fix "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter '?

Tags: c#, object

I was trying to do a class library in order to create objects and transfer their information into a database

Unforntuantly I have a problem with inheritance on my class `Software`, which are child classes for `Produto`

```
class Produto
{    
    public Produto(string codproduto, string designacao, double preco, int stock, double iva)
    {    
        this.codproduto = codproduto;
        this.designacao = designacao;
        this.preco = preco;
        this.stock = stock;    
    }

    private string codproduto;
    private string designacao;
    private double preco;
    private int stock;

    public string CodProduto
    {    
        get { return codproduto; }
        set { codproduto = value; }        
    }

    public string Designacao
    {    
        get { return designacao; }
        set { designacao = value; }        
    }

    public double Preco
    {    
        get { return preco; }
        set { preco = value; }        
    }

    public int Quantidade
    {
        get { return stock; }
        set { stock = value; }    
    }


    class Software : Produto
    {    
        public Software(string marca, string sistemaoperativo, string tiposoftware)
        {    
            this.marca = marca;
            this.sistemaoperativo = sistemaoperativo;
            this.tiposoftware = tiposoftware;        
        }

        private string marca;
        private string sistemaoperativo;
        private string tiposoftware;

        public string Marca
        {    
            get { return marca; }
            set { marca = value; }
        }

        public string SistemaOperativo
        {    
            get { return sistemaoperativo; }
            set { sistemaoperativo = value; }    
        }

        public string TipoSoftware
        {    
            get { return tiposoftware; }
            set { tiposoftware = value; }    
        }                
    }
}
```

The error shown is :

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'codproduto' of 'Produto.Produto(string, string, double,
>   int, double)'

Comment: You need to call the  Produto  constructor e.g.
 `public Software(string marca, string sistemaoperativo, string tiposoftware): base(....)`
Or add a default constructor to Produto with no params

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inheritance with base class constructor with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696006/inheritance-with-base-class-constructor-with-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

if you declare a constructor with parameters in the base class, then the compiler will force you to call it in the derived class. This is what this (informative) error message is trying to tell you.

The reason is quite simple. When you want to create an instance of a derived class then the constructor of the base class will be called **before** it! So it will need all the parameters that you have defined.

To avoid a huge set of parameters for the `Software` constructor you can pass a base class object into it and the call the base constructor passing the necessary variables into it:

```
class Software : Produto
{

    public Software(string marca, string sistemaoperativo, string tiposoftware, Produto baseInfo, double iva)
                : base(baseInfo.codproduto, baseInfo.designacao, baseInfo.preco, baseInfo.stock, iva)
    {
```

Answer (score 1):

Your child class needs to call the base-class constructor, or define a public parameter-less constructor. (the automatic one goes away when you define a constructor with parameters)

```
class Software : Produto
    {

        public Software(string marca, string sistemaoperativo, string tiposoftware)
        {
```

Software constructor needs to be:

```
public Software(string marca, string sistemaoperativo, string tiposoftwarestring codproduto, string designacao, double preco, int stock, double iva):base(designacao,preco,stock,iva){
```