# How to write the properties of a class in separate file/class that shares same object instance

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I am setting up a Framework for the Selenium test automation using c# and Page object model.

the framework is setup using specflow,which has project structure as below.

- Feature file
- Step definition
- core.cs

code of core is as follows:

```cs
[Binding]
public class Core
{
    private readonly IObjectContainer objectContainer;
    public IWebDriver _driver;
    public Core(IObjectContainer objContainer) => objectContainer = objContainer;

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void BeforeScenario()
    {
        _driver = new ChromeDriver();
        objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<IWebDriver>(_driver);
    }
}
```

And step definition as follows:

```cs
[Binding]
public class StepDefinition
{
    public IWebDriver driver;
    public StepDefinition1(IWebDriver _driver) => driver = _driver;

    public IWebElement username => driver.FindElement(By.Id("username"));//property1
    public IWebElement password => driver.FindElement(By.Id("pass"));//property2
    .
    .
    .
    .

    [When(@"i enter data")]
    public void WhenIEnterData()
    {
        username.Click()              
    }
}
```

I would like to have the `password` and `username` properties in separate a file. There will be many properties in future and many step definition files. so i want to keep all the properties in one place.

I Tried splitting the class and marking both as partial class and use same name, but if there are many step definition files this will not work.

```cs
public class OR
{ 
    public IWebDriver driver;
    public OR(IWebDriver _driver) => driver = _driver;
    public IWebElement username => driver.FindElement(By.Id("username"));
    public IWebElement password => driver.FindElement(By.Id("pass"));
}

[Binding]
public class StepDefinition1 :OR
{
    public IWebDriver driver;
    public StepDefinition1(IWebDriver _driver) => driver = _driver;

    [When(@"i enter data")]
    public void WhenIEnterData()
    {
        username.Click();
    }
}
```

but this gives me:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter `_driver` of `OR.OR(IWebDriver)` on constructor of stepdefnition1.

As there will be many step definition files i would like to keep all the properties on one place and accessible to all classes/step definitions.

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out what you're asking exactly. It kind of sounds like you're asking about `partial` classes, but you said that doesn't work. Are you saying you have many `StepDefinitionX` classes, and  they all share a common set of properties? So, every `StepDefinition` will have the `username` and `password` property, for example?

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson yes, all the stepdefinitions will have some common set of properties and some distinct. my intention is to keep all the properties in one place so that all stepdefinitions can access that.

Answer (score 2):

While Ikacho's answer would solve the problem, your question is better solved with a different architecture for your classes. Keep the step definition classes and selenium related classes separate, and utilize the Page Object Model.

First, the page object, which specializes in the login page:

```cs
public class LoginPage
{ 
    public IWebDriver driver;

    public LoginPage(IWebDriver _driver)
    {
        this.driver = _driver;
    }

    private IWebElement Username => driver.FindElement(By.Id("username"));
    private IWebElement Password => driver.FindElement(By.Id("pass"));
    private IWebElement LoginButton => driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(., 'Login']"));

    public void LogIn(string username, string password)
    {
        Username.SendKeys(username);
        Password.SendKeys(password);
        LoginButton.Click();
    }
}
```

And a sample step definition file:

```cs
[Binding]
public class StepDefinition1
{
    private IWebDriver driver;
    private LoginPage loginPage;

    public StepDefinition1(IWebDriver _driver)
    {
        driver = _driver;
        loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
    }

    [When(@"I log in")]
    public void WhenIEnterData()
    {
        loginPage.LogIn("test", "test");
    }
}
```

Now the code that interacts with the web browser using the Selenium API is centralized in their own classes, giving you an easy way to reuse that code. It also allows you to create classes that can handle the intricate details of interacting with the web page, so this complexity is not spread out over your step definitions.

No need for inheritance at all. Composition will be simpler and easier to reuse code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the base class OR has no parameterless constructor. So you must call constructor of the base class with parameters from constructor of the derived class:

```
public StepDefinition1(IWebDriver _driver) : base(_driver) 
{
    driver = _driver;
}
```

[Original source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696006/inheritance-with-base-class-constructor-with-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you pretty much just want to split up a single class into multiple files. If so, what you want is the `partial` keyword:

```
//Foo.cs
partial class Foo {
    private Bar Baz;
}

//FooExtended.cs
partial class Foo {
    private void qux() {
        //you can use private members in here, just as if it would be one class definition
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods

Comment: Yes this works, but if there are many stepdefinition classes, this will not work. looks like inheritance is only solution to me, but I am getting error as said.